# I can't format my USB pendrive (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, linux-mint, format

I want to format my pendrive in Linux Mint. However, when I connect it to my laptop, it cant see the pendrive. However, `lsusb` sees it:

[image]

The `disks` utility however, cant format it because of the error message:

[image]

`Gparted` says that theres an input/output error, `fdisk -l` cant see it.

[image]

What else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried the drive on another computer to see if the drive is faulty?

Comment: Also, check it with gparted to see if it has one valid partition.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Unfortunately, I do not have another computer. I need to wait till monday, I could check at work. But I would like to fix it, if possible, today.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: But how? Gparted says its and input/output error on this pendrive, and I cannot access it using Gparted.

Comment: Your USB flash drive appears to be deceased. As @AndrewMorton suggests, try another PC, but don't get your hopes up.